# How to read manually added text within a pdf file with c#?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

i'm using iTextSharp with this C# code:

```
string parsedText = string.Empty;

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);


            ITextExtractionStrategy its = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
            parsedText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1, its);

            parsedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(parsedText)));
```

It parses the pdf as expected, but it does not parse text, that is manually added with tools like FoxItReader oder NuancePDF.
Our accounting is manually adding an internal invoicenumber on each pdf and I need to parse that number. For some reason i can't find it.

It looks like it is on another "layer" of something that is not parsed.

Any ideas how to read those numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the internal invoice number is being added as an annotation, rather than as actual text on the page.

Have you tried iText's facilities for extracting annotations to see if there are any on the page?